# Main thread warning with CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()

Tags: swift, ios16, xcode14

I just upgraded to Xcode 14.0 and when I run our app on iOS 16 devices, calls to:

`CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()`

Are returning the warning:

**This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first.**

I'd need to make significant changes to my code if I have to wait for a failure/callback rather than just calling the `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` method directly.  This only seems to happen on iOS 16 devices.  Any suggests on how to address this?

Comment: don't you ask for authorization if you don't have it? and if you do, that would be the same code as apple wants you to implement here (i.e. regardless of current authorization status, ask for it, and process an async response)

Comment: @khjfquantumjj You know that `authorizationStatus` and `locationServicesEnabled()` are returning two entirely distinct statuses, right?

Comment: @AlanSTACK read the question. Based on warning the OP receives, it could be that he is trying to get `locationServicesEnabled` when user didn't authorize the access to location services, while authorization is a prerequisite to be able to obtain `locationServicesEnabled` status.

Comment: None of the suggested solutions worked for me.  I had to reconfigure my code to move this call off the main thread.  I couldn't find another way around it.

Comment: @akjndklskver @AlanSTACK You can check `authorizationStatus` on a `CLLocationManager` instance without having permission. If the user has not granted permission, then the status will be `denied`.

Comment: @bugloaf You're wrong: The status might be denied because user disabled only for that app:
1) If you disable location services: `status = denied, locationServicesEnabled = false`
2) If you disable location services only for your app: `status = denied, locationServicesEnabled = true`
3) If you enable for both of them: `status = always/while using.., locationServicesEnabled = true`

Answer (score 36):

Use a dispatch queue to move it off the main queue like so:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
  if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Two other options are to wrap in `Task.detached` or use `async let enabled = CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` when `await enabled` within a Task. 

Any comments which is preferred?

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue and overcame it using **Async/Await**.

Wrap the `CLLocationManager` call in an async function.

```
func locationServicesEnabled() async -> Bool {
    CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
}
```

Then update the places where you use this function accordingly.

```
Task { [weak self] in

    if await self?.locationServicesEnabled() { 
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This still gives me the same warning.

Comment: This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first.

Comment: Yes, the example code above should consider that Tasks inherit the context in which they're instantiated.

Comment: Putting the `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` call in an async func doesn't actually make it asynchronous since there isn't anything to await.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling locationServicesEnabled directly, wrap it in a thread safe manner:

```
extension CLLocationManager {
func locationServicesEnabledThreadSafe(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
         let result = CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(result)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Usage example:

```
    CLLocationManager().locationServicesEnabledThreadSafe { [weak self] areEnabled in
        guard let self = self else {
            return assertionFailure()
        }
        self.handleLocationServices(enabled: areEnabled)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must to return a value for example from
`func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool`
you can run it in the `DispatchQueue.global()` and await for execution with a `DispatchSemaphore` like this:

```
private func hasLocationPermission() -> Bool {
    var hasPermission = false
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        //This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch manager.authorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                hasPermission = false
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                hasPermission = true
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        } else {
            hasPermission = false
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    return hasPermission
}
```

then

```
  func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {
    return hasLocationPermission()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to separate both main.async and global().async to check some options in the background.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite new to Swift but with iOS 17 i've found this to work instead of checking locationServicesEnabled() you check the authorizationStatus:

```
func checkLocationServicesEnabled() {
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager() // initialise location manager if location services is enabled
    self.locationManager!.delegate = self // force unwrap since created location manager on line above so not much of a way this can go wrong
    self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    
    switch self.locationManager?.authorizationStatus { // check authorizationStatus instead of locationServicesEnabled()
        case .notDetermined, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .restricted, .denied:
            print("ALERT: no location services access")
    case .authorizedAlways:
        break
    case .none, .some(_):
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).