# Resolving CoreLocation UI unresponsiveness error on Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, location

When I try to get my current location in flutter with the default location package, I receive a core location error. My permissions on my device are enabled to allow location for the application and there are no other errors aside from when I try to open the map. As a result of this error, my current location coordinates are never returned from the function.

Full error:

`` [CoreLocation] This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first. ``

Thus far, I have tried a clean pod install and altering the permissions I have in info.plist. The only related issue to this involves Geolocation rather than default location ([Flutter: geolocator Error? Warning? [CoreLocation] This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked ... . I can't get GPS information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75242557/flutter-geolocator-error-warning-corelocation-this-method-can-cause-ui-unre)).

```
void getCurrentLocation () {
    Location location = Location(); // never executes past this point

    location.getLocation().then(
      (location) {
        currentLocation = location;
    });
}
```

Above is the code snippet in question. Additionally, this is my app delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("KEY")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  
  }

}
```